# Browser overrides my CSS font

Tags: html, css

I've built a website. In all browsers everything looks cool and nice.

But today one of my clients discovered that in his opera browser the fonts are different. It's a computer font, I mean, you can't use that font by css, it's some custom font.

in CSS file, for that text fonts and as a default Body font I have sylfaen, calibri, georgia, helvetica, arial; and suddenly the fonts are not even closer to one of the fonts mentioned in my CSS.

one more thing is that, in some places we have sylfaen, and in some cases that stupid font.

What can be the problem?

```
    body { background: url(../images/intro_bg.jpg) top center; background-attachment:fixed; margin:0; padding:0;
    font:normal 12px Calibri, Sylfaen, Georgia, Tahoma, Arial; color:#898a8c; line-height: 140%; }

    img { border: none; }

.wrapper { width:1001px; height:554px; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; }
#wrapper { width:1000px; margin:0px auto 0px auto; position: relative;}
    .flash { background-color: #fff; width:343px; height:554px; float:left; }
    .form { background:url(../images/intro.jpg); width:624px; height:554px; float:right; } 
        .date { margin-top:372px; padding-left:120px; }
        .date input { background:url(../images/intro_form.png) top center no-repeat; width:92px; height:50px; border:none; 
                font:normal 40px/50px Calibri, Sylfaen, Georgia, Tahoma, Arial; color: #939598; text-align:center; margin-right:9px; }
        .country { margin-top:38px; width:213px; margin-left:85px; }
        .country select { height:18px; width:213px; font:normal 12px/18px Calibri, Sylfaen, Georgia, Tahoma, Arial; color: #939598; }
        p.buttons { margin: 50px 0 0 0; padding-left: 2px;} 
        p.buttons input.geo { background:url(../images/geo.png) no-repeat; width:113px; height:24px; border:none; margin-left: 6px; text-indent:-9999px; }
        p.buttons input.geo:hover { cursor: pointer; }      
        p.buttons input.eng { background:url(../images/eng.png) no-repeat; width:113px; height:24px; border:none; margin-left: 8px; text-indent:-9999px; }
        p.buttons input.eng:hover { cursor: pointer; }          
        p.buttons input.rus { background:url(../images/rus.png) no-repeat; width:113px; height:24px; border:none; margin-left: 9px; text-indent:-9999px; }
        p.buttons input.rus:hover { cursor: pointer; }          
        .shadow { background:url(../images/shadow.png) top center no-repeat; width:1034px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:0px; }

        #header { width:1000px; height:305px; }
        .header-top { background: url(../images/header-top.jpg) top center no-repeat; height:106px; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;}
        .logo { width: 171px; height: 106px; margin:0 auto; }

        .header-banner {  width: 1000px; height: 159px; margin:0 auto; }
        .menu-right { background:none; float: right; width:120px; height:40px; margin: 0 16px 0 0; }


        #menu { background:#887b33; height:40px; width:1000px; margin:0; padding:0; }
        .menu-main { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 40px; width: 700px; float: left; }
        .menu-main li { display:inline; border-right: solid 1px #a39961; }
        .menu-main li:hover { display:inline; border-right: solid 1px #a39961; }
        .menu-main li img { display:none; }



.menu-main ul
    {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    z-index:500;
    display:none;
    margin:0;
    border:none;
    }

.menu-main ul ul
    {
    top:0;
    left:100%;
border:none;    
    }

div#menu li:hover ul ul,
div#menu li li:hover ul ul,
div#menu li li li:hover ul ul,
div#menu li li li li:hover ul ul
{display:none; border:none; }

div#menu li:hover ul,
div#menu li li:hover ul,
div#menu li li li:hover ul,
div#menu li li li li:hover ul
{display:block; border:none; }      

div#menu li ul li  { height: 20px; border:none; }       
div#menu li ul li  a{ background: #b1a676; color: #fff; height: 30px; font: normal 12px/30px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Arial, Verdana; text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 8px; border:none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.1); }        
div#menu li ul li  a:hover { background: #887b32; color: #fff; border:none; }       


div#menu div.menu-right div#jflanguageselection ul.jflanguageselection { width:120px; margin:0; padding:0; margin-top: 11px; text-align: right; 
    margin-right: -5px; float:right; }
div#menu div.menu-right div#jflanguageselection ul.jflanguageselection li{ width:20px; margin:0; padding:0; display:inline; margin-right: 5px; }
div#menu div.menu-right div#jflanguageselection ul.jflanguageselection li a{ font: normal 14px calibri, georgia, sylfaen, verdana; 
    text-decoration: none; color:#fff; text-transform: uppercase; }

        #content-holder { background:#fff url(../images/cont_shd.png) top center repeat-x; width:964px; padding:25px 18px 20px 18px; }
            .left { width:111px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0;  margin-right:17px;}
            .left-menu { width:145px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0; background: #fff; margin-left:-18px; }
            .left-menu2 { width:145px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0; background: #fff; margin-left:-18px; }
            .right { width:111px; float:right; margin:0; padding:0; }
                .right img { margin-bottom:20px;}
        .content-main { width:677px; float:left; border-left:solid 1px #c5c7c8; border-right: solid 1px #c5c7c8;
            padding: 0 14px; }
        .content-main-wine { width:810px; float:left; border-left:solid 1px #b2b4b6; border-right: solid 0px #8a8d08;
            padding: 0 0 0 14px; }
        .content-search { width:677px; float:left; border-left:solid 1px #c5c7c8; border-right: solid 1px #c5c7c8;
            padding: 0 14px; min-height:450px; }            


        #article { width:677px; border-bottom:solid 1px #c6c785; padding: 0 0 20px 0; margin: 0 0 20px 0; }
            .article-image { width:148px; float:left;}
            .article-cont { width:510px; float:right; }
            .art-title { margin: -5px 0 5px 0; font:normal 20px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Tahoma, Arial; color:#8a8e06; }
            .art-text { margin:0; }
            .read-more { margin: 5px 0 0 0; }
            .read-more a { font:normal 12px Calibri, Sylfaen, Georgia, Tahoma, Arial; color:#7c202b; text-decoration:none; }

        #bot_cont { background: #35311c; width: 964px; height:150px; padding: 15px 18px 15px 18px; }
            .holder { float: left; margin-right: 15px; }
            .holder h3 { color: #8b8e09; font: bold 14px Calibri, Sylfaen, Georgia, Tahoma, Arial; border-right: solid 2px #887b32; margin: 0 0px 10px 0; width:140px }
            .holder ul.lists { width:140px; float: left; margin:0; padding:0; margin-right:15px; }
            .holder ul.menu-lists { width:140px; float: left; margin:0; padding:0; margin-right:15px; }
            .holder ul.small { width: 80px; }
            .holder ul.menu-lists li { list-style:none; margin-bottom:0px; }
            .holder ul.menu-lists li { list-style:none; margin-bottom:0px; }
            .holder ul.lists li { list-style:none; margin-bottom:0px; }
            .holder ul.menu-lists li a { color: #fff; font: normal 13px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Tahoma, Arial; line-height: 130%; text-decoration:none; }            
            .holder ul.lists li a { color: #fff; font: normal 13px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Tahoma, Arial; line-height: 130%; text-decoration:none; }         
            .holder ul.icons { float:left; margin:0; padding:0; }
            .holder ul.icons li { display:inline; list-style:none; margin-right:15px; }
            .holder h3.last { border: none; }           

            .buyonline { margin-top: 15px; float: left; height:29px; width:111px; }                     




        #footer { background: #887b32; width: 1000px; height: 24px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-top:6px; }
            .copyright { margin: 0 0 0 10px; color: #fff; float: left; }
            .developed { margin: 0 10px 0 0; color: #fff; float: right; }
            .developed a { color: #fff; text-decoration:none; }         


.tree ul {  margin:0; padding:0; width:145px; list-style:none; }
.tree ul li ul { margin:0; padding:0; width:145px; list-style:none; }
.tree ul li ul li a { font: normal 12px/20px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#7b212b; display:block;
     text-decoration:none; text-indent: 10px; margin-bottom: 1px; }
.tree ul li ul li a:hover { background-color: #b57978; color:#fff; }     
.tree ul li ul li a.sublevel_active { background-color: #7b212b; color:#fff; }   
.tree ul li ul li a#active_menu { background-color: #7b212b; color:#fff; }   


.tree ul li ul li ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
.tree ul li ul li ul  li {  text-indent: 20px; }
.tree ul li ul li ul li a { background-color: #fff; font: normal 12px/20px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    color:#808285; display:block; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; margin-bottom: 1px; }
.tree ul li ul li ul li a:hover { background-color: #ada05a; color:#fff; }      
.tree ul li ul li ul li a.sublevel_active { background-color: #887b32; color:#fff; }        
.tree ul li ul li ul li a#active_menu { background-color: #887b32; color:#fff; }        


.tree ul li ul li ul li ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;  }
.tree ul li ul li ul li ul li a { background-color: #fff; font: normal 12px/20px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    color:#cbbc9a; display:block; text-transform:capitalize; text-decoration:none; text-indent: 28px; margin-bottom: 1px; } 
.tree ul li ul li ul li ul li a:hover { background-color: #d3ceb1; color:#fff; }        
.tree ul li ul li ul li ul li a.sublevel_active{ background-color: #cbbc9a; color:#fff; }       
.tree ul li ul li ul li ul li a#active_menu{ background-color: #cbbc9a; color:#fff; }       


.tree ul li ul li ul li ul li ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;  } 
.tree ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a { background-color: #fff; font: normal 12px/20px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    color:#887b32; display:block; text-transform:capitalize; text-decoration:none; text-indent: 33px; margin-bottom: 1px; } 
.tree ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a:hover { background-color: #e2dec9; color:#fff; list-style:none; }
.tree ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a.sublevel_active { background-color: #e2dec9; color:#fff; list-style:none; }
.tree ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a#active_menu { background-color: #e2dec9; color:#fff; list-style:none; }



div.content-main-wine { color: #808285; text-align: left; }
div.content-main-wine h2 { font: normal 18px sylfaen, georgia, verdana, aria, calibri; margin: 0 0 10px 0; color: #000; }

#wineholder { width: 680px; border-bottom: solid 1px #c5c7c8; padding-bottom: 10px; float:left; margin-bottom:20px; }
#wineholder-large { width: 690px; border-bottom: solid 0px #c5c7c8; padding-bottom: 10px; float:left; }
#wineholder-large  p { margin-bottom: 20px; }
.winesimage-small { float: left; border:0; }
.winesimage { float: left; border:0; margin-right:10px; }
.wine-title { color: #7b212b; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Georgia, Calibri, Verdana, Arial;  float: left; width: 577px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: -5px; margin-left: 3px; }
table.contentpaneopen h3 { color: #7b212b; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top:10px; }  
.wine-descript-short h3 { color: #7b212b; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom:5px; } 
table.contentpaneopen h4 { color: #808285; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top:10px; }  
table.contentpaneopen h6 { color: #887b32; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top:10px; }  
table.contentpaneopen tr td table tr td p { margin-bottom: 25px; line-height:160%; }
table.contentpaneopen tr td div p { margin-bottom: 17px; line-height:160%; }
table.contentpaneopen { width:100% }
.wine-descript-short { width: 577px; float: left; margin-left: 3px; text-align: left; }
.wine-descript-short p { margin: 0; }
p.readmore { float:left;  margin: 25px 0 0 3px; }
p.readmore a { color: #cbbc9a; text-decoration: none; font: normal 12px Calibri, Sylfaen, Georgia, Arial; }

.redtext { color: #7c212a; }
.readon { color: #cbbc9a; text-decoration: none; }


.contact { width:300px; border-right: dashed 1px #c5c7c8; margin:0; padding:0; padding-right:10px; float: left; }
.contact  a { color: #887b32; font: normal 12px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; text-decoration:none; }
.contact  span { color: #35321c; font: normal 12px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; text-decoration:none; }

div.left-menu2 div.moduletable h3 { color: #887b33; font: bold 12px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; text-decoration:none; text-indent:17px;}

.menu-left2 { margin:6px 0 0 0; padding:0; list-style:none; width:145px; }
.menu-left2 li { list-style:none; width:145px; margin-bottom:1px; }
.menu-left2 li a { 
background: #fff;
display: block;
padding: 2px 5px 2px 25px;
text-decoration: none;
/* text-indent: 25px; */
font: normal 12px/20px calibri, sylfaen, georgia, verdana;
color: #808285;
 }

.menu-left2 li a:hover { background: #ada05a; color: #fff; }
.menu-left2 li.active a { 
background: #887b33;
color: #fff;
 } 

.contact-form { width:385px; float: left; margin-left: 30px; } 
input.rapid_contact.inputbox, #user_name_formAcymailing1, #user_email_formAcymailing1  { border-top: solid 1px #6d6f71; border-left: solid 1px #6d6f71; border-right: solid 1px #918f90; border-bottom: solid 1px #c9c8c8;
    width:145px; color:#808285; font:normal 12px sylfaen, georgia, calibri, arial; }

input.rapid_contact.button, .subbutton { width:64px; height:21px; background:url(../images/send_btn.png) no-repeat; border:none; margin-top:8px; margin-left: -2px;
    color: #fff; font: normal 12px/21px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; }    

textarea.rapid_contact.textarea { border-top: solid 1px #6d6f71; border-left: solid 1px #6d6f71; border-right: solid 1px #918f90; border-bottom: solid 1px #c9c8c8;
    width:252px; height:100px; }    

span.contact-label { padding: 0 10px 0 0; } 

.telianiworld, .telianiworld-details { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; margin-left:10px; }    
.telianiworld { float:left; margin-right:60px; margin-left:10px; }      
.telianiworld li { list-style:none; margin-bottom:6px; }            
.telianiworld li  a, .telianiworld-title { color: #7b212b; font: normal 13px Sylfaen, Georgia, Calibri, Verdana, Arial; text-decoration:none; text-transform: uppercase; margin:0; }        
.telianiworld-link a { color: #887b33; font: normal 14px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; text-decoration:none; } 
.telianiworld-details p { margin-bottom:0; }
.telianiworld-details p a { color: #887b33; font: normal 14px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; text-decoration:none; }


.menu-addition, .menu-addition li ul, .menu-addition li ul li ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important; }
.menu-addition li { list-style:none; /* margin-bottom: 1px; */ font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important; }
.menu-addition li a { 
background: #fff;
display: block;
padding: 2px 0 5px 18px;
text-decoration: none;
/* text-indent: 25px; */
font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
color: #7c222b; 
margin-bottom:1px;
}

.menu-addition li a:hover { font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
background: #b57978;
color: #fff;
 }  
.menu-addition li.active a {  font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
background: #7c222b;
color: #fff;
 } 

.menu-addition li ul li { margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:0; font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important; } 

.menu-addition li ul li a, .menu-addition li ul li.item23 a, .menu-addition li ul li.item24 a,
 .menu-addition li ul li.item25 a, .menu-addition li ul li.item26 a { 
background: #fff;
display: block;
padding: 2px 5px 5px 25px;
text-decoration: none;
/* text-indent: 25px; */
font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
color: #808285;
}

.menu-addition li ul li.item23.active a, .menu-addition li ul li.item24.active a,
.menu-addition li ul li.item25.active a, .menu-addition li ul li.item26.active a { background: #887b32; color: #fff; font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; }

.menu-addition li ul li.item23 a:hover, .menu-addition li ul li.item24 a:hover,
.menu-addition li ul li.item25 a:hover, .menu-addition li ul li.item26 a:hover { background: #ada05a; color: #fff; font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; }

.menu-addition li ul li li { font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important; }
.menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item27 a, .menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item28 a, .menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item29 a { 
background: #ffffff !important; 
display: block;
color: #bab186 !important;
padding: 2px 0 3px 40px;
text-decoration: none;
font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
}

.menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item27 a:hover,
.menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item28 a:hover,
.menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item29 a:hover  { 
background: #d3ceb1!important; 
display: block;
color: #fff !important;
padding: 2px 0 3px 40px;
text-decoration: none;
font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
}


.menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item27.active a, 
.menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item28.active a,
.menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item29.active a  { 
background: #bab186 !important; 
display: block;
color: #fff !important;
padding: 2px 0 3px 40px;
text-decoration: none;
font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
}

.menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item29 a, .menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item29 a:hover, .menu-addition  li ul li ul li.item29.active a  { width: 102px; padding: 2px 4px 3px 40px; font: normal 10px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important; }
span.green { color:#887b32; }
span.pale { color:#cbbc9a; margin-top:20px; }
span.pale p { padding-left:0px; margin:0; }

.trading-left { float: left; width:543px; margin-top:0px; }
.trading-right { float: right; width:207px; margin-top:10px; margin-left:0px; }
.trading-right p { font: normal 12px sylfaen, georgia, arial, calibri; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:0; }
.trading-right a { font: normal 12px sylfaen, georgia, arial, calibri; color:#7b212b; text-decoration:none; margin-top:0px; }

table.trading-cell { margin-top:0px; border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom:20px; }
table.trading-cell tr { border-bottom: dashed 1px #c5c6c8; }
table.trading-cell tr td img { margin-left:25px; }
div.trad-title { width:145px; height:23px; font: normal 12px/23px sylfaen, georgia, arial, sylfaen; 
    color: #fff; text-align: right; float: left; background: #bbb187; padding-right: 5px; }

p.indent a { text-decoration:none; color:#887b32; margin-top:0; }   

div.front-article { margin-top:-15px; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom: solid 1px #c5c7c8; padding-bottom:8px;}

div.archive-title { width:105px; }
div.archive-title a { color:#7b212b; font:normal 18px sylfaen, georgia, arial, calibri; float:left;  text-decoration:none; }
div.archive-desc { color:#808285; font:normal 12px sylfaen, georgia, arial, calibri; float:right;  width:705px; padding-right: 0px;}

#archive-list li { margin-bottom:20px; }

button.archive-btn { width:51px; height:21px; background:url(../images/select.jpg) no-repeat; border:none; margin-left: 10px;
    color: #fff; font: normal 12px/21px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial;}

.newsletter { width:300px; float:left; }    

ul.menu-lists.siaxleebi { width:90px }
ul.menu-lists.galerchika { width:75px }
ul.menu-lists.investorebi { width:120px }

dl.system-message { display:none; }

        .content-video { width:750px; padding: 0 0 0 0px; margin:0 auto; }  
        .gallery { width: 690px; padding: 0 10px 20px 0px; border-right: dashed 0px #c5c7c8; float: left; }
        .content-photos { width:690px; padding: 0 0 0 0px; margin:0 auto; }
        .moduletablegallery h3 { margin: 10px 0 10px 0; font: normal 12px Sylfaen, Georgia, Arial, Verdana, Calibri;  color:#898a8c; }
        .video-holder { float: left; width: 210px; margin:0 20px; }
        .viewmorevids { margin: 0 0 0 10px; width: 500px; }
        .viewmorevids a { font: normal 12px Sylfaen, Georgia, Arial, Verdana, Calibri;  color:#7b212b; }    
        a.ytb img { vertical-align:bottom; margin-left:10px; }  

    .list-awards { width:110px; border-left: dashed 1px #b2b4b6; float: right; padding-left: 10px; }
    .list-awards-wide { width:100px; border-left: dashed 1px #b2b4b6; float: right; padding-left: 10px; height:400px; }

.content-main-wine .jcb_fieldValue { line-height: 150%; }

.red-filter { display:block; width:60px; height:17px; background:#7c212a; margin-right: 4px;
font: normal 10px/17px sylfaen, georgia, arial, calibri; text-align: center; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; float:left; }

.white-filter   { display:block; width:60px; height:17px; background:#887b32; margin-right: 4px;
font: normal 10px/17px sylfaen, georgia, arial, calibri; text-align: center; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; float:left; }

.rose-filter    { display:block; width:75px; height:17px; background:#bc5168; margin-right: 4px;
font: normal 10px/17px sylfaen, georgia, arial, calibri; text-align: center; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; float:left; }

.icons a.pdf { display:block; background: url(../images/pdf_button.png) no-repeat; width:19px; height:21px; text-indent:-9999px; float:left; margin-right:3px; }
.icons a.print { display:block; background: url(../images/print_button.png) no-repeat; width:19px; height:21px; text-indent:-9999px; float:left; margin-right:3px; }
.icons a.email { display:block; background: url(../images/email_button.png) no-repeat; width:18px; height:15px; 
    text-indent:-9999px; float:left; vertical-align:bottom; margin-top:5px; margin-right:3px; }

.content-sitemap div.xmap { width:600px; margin:0 0 0 220px; }
.content-sitemap div.xmap  ul li a { color:#454545; text-decoration:none; font:normal 12px Calibri, Sylfaen, Georgia, Tahoma, Arial; color:#898a8c; }
.content-sitemap div.xmap  ul li a:hover { color:#62551a; text-decoration:none; }
.content-sitemap div.xmap  ul.level_2 { display:none; }

div.search { width:140px; margin-top:55px; }
.search input.inputbox { border:none; background: url(../images/search_bg.png) no-repeat; width:85px; height:20px; padding-left:8px;
    font: normal 12px/20px Calibri, Sylfaen, Georgia, Arial, Verdana;  color:#454545; margin:0;  vertical-align: top; }
.search input.button, button.searchbtn-search { border:none; background: url(../images/search_btn.png) no-repeat; width:24px; height:20px; text-indent:-9999px; 
    margin:0 0 0 -1px; vertical-align: top; }
input.searchbox-search { border:none; background: url(../images/search_bg-big.png) no-repeat; width:242px; height:20px; padding-left:8px;
    font: normal 12px/20px Calibri, Sylfaen, Georgia, Arial, Verdana;  color:#454545; margin:0;  vertical-align: top; margin-right:-3px; margin-left:20px;} 

span.awardlist-title { font: normal 18px/24px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Arial, Verdana;  color:#7b212b; }  
span.awardlist-desc { font: normal 18px/24px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Arial, Verdana;  color:#808285;}            
span.awardlist-mosavali { font: normal 18px/18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Arial, Verdana;  color:#887b32; }           

div.awardlist-list { width:661px; border-bottom: solid 1px #b2b4b6; padding: 10px 0; height: 44px; margin-left: 42px; }
img.awardlist-image { float: right; }
span.awardlist-awardtitle { font: normal 12px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Arial, Verdana;  color:#808285; float: left; 
    margin-top: 18px;}

.search-title { color:#62551a; font: normal 12px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Arial, Verdana; line-height:150%; } 
.search-title:hover { text-decoration: underline }  

p.search-options { margin-left:-6px; margin-bottom:0; }
p.results-search { margin-left:3px; }

#searchphraseall, #searchphraseany, #searchphraseexact { 
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0px dotted #9900FF; color: #ccc; }


.map-tabs { margin:-3px 0 0 0; padding:0; } 
.map-tabs div.moduletable { margin:0; padding:0; }  
.map-tabs p { margin:0; padding:0; }
.kaxeti-btn { background-color:#887b32; padding: 3px 10px; color:#fff; margin-right: 10px; }
.imereti-btn { background-color:#b79f72; padding: 3px 10px; color:#fff; margin-right: 10px; }
.racha-btn { background-color:#7c222b; padding: 3px 10px; color:#fff; margin-right: 10px; }
.shavi-btn { background-color:#008570; padding: 3px 10px; color:#fff; margin-right: 10px; }
.kartli-btn { background-color:#ca6419; padding: 3px 10px; color:#fff; margin-right: 10px; }
.tab-desc { color: #808285; font: normal 12px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Arial, Verdana; }

p.kaxeti { color: #887b32; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; margin:0; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top:10px; }    
p.imereti { color: #b79f72; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; margin:0; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top:10px; }   
p.racha { color: #7c222b; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; margin:0; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top:10px; } 
p.shavi { color: #008570; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial; margin:0; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top:10px; } 
p.kartli { color: #ca6419; font: normal 18px Sylfaen, Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, Arial;margin:0;  margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top:10px; }
```

Here's the code :)

Comment: please show us your CSS font code -- it may be you've got something wrong which Opera doesn't like, but we'll never know unless you show us the actal code.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the user has set a default text for his browser? (Not sure if this is possible to overwrite all text, but i've heard of it, and otherwise they do it when they do not recognize the font)

Have you tested it yourself on Opera?

Comment: I disabled the user fonts and style-s in Opera but we still have it. on 2 different Opera-s everything is alright, just on the one particular Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using @font-face? if not - it is entirely possible that your client doesn't have the font installed in his system

Comment: that's the problem, he has those fonts

Answer (score 1):

Its worth pointing out that Calibri and Sylfaen were only added to Windows in Windows Vista. Users with older versions (XP, etc) may not have these fonts. In this case, it'll fall back to Georgia, which may give quite a different look.

Further, all of the fonts you specified are owned by Microsoft, so users of other operating systems may not have *any* of them.

In our site, we found that in order to support Calibri as the default font, we actually needed to make it available for download using the CSS `@font-face` declaration.

The basic syntax looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "CalibriForMac";
    src: url("../fonts/calibri.ttf");
}
```

but you may want to read some of the many examples on the web, as there are a number of cross-browser and cross-operating-system issues with using `@font-face`.

Here's one page which discusses it: http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/